# What Is The Mechanism To Refresh Access Token

Tags: oauth2

In RFC 6749 Section 4.4 regarding Client Credentials Grant:

```
4.4.  Client Credentials Grant

   The client can request an access token using only its client
   credentials (or other supported means of authentication) when the
   client is requesting access to the protected resources under its
   control, or those of another resource owner that have been previously
   arranged with the authorization server (the method of which is beyond
   the scope of this specification).




Hardt                        Standards Track                   [Page 40]

RFC 6749                        OAuth 2.0                   October 2012


   The client credentials grant type MUST only be used by confidential
   clients.

     +---------+                                  +---------------+
     |         |                                  |               |
     |         |>--(A)- Client Authentication --->| Authorization |
     | Client  |                                  |     Server    |
     |         |<--(B)---- Access Token ---------<|               |
     |         |                                  |               |
     +---------+                                  +---------------+

                     Figure 6: Client Credentials Flow

   The flow illustrated in Figure 6 includes the following steps:

   (A)  The client authenticates with the authorization server and
        requests an access token from the token endpoint.

   (B)  The authorization server authenticates the client, and if valid,
        issues an access token.
```

It states that

> A refresh token SHOULD NOT be included

In this scenario, how should the token be refreshed if not supplied in the response? It will mean that the client will have to re-authenticate to get another access token.

Answer (score 1):

the Client Credentials Grant should only be used in use cases where you can trust both endpoints (e.a. you control both ends).

as an example when being used in a server-server connection. for these connections you would never need a refresh token because for the rare case your token has expired you can simply redo the original request.

(your app has all the data to do the full request to get an access  token again).

having a refresh token would mean you open a secondary vector by having another credential that represent your authorization and authentication.

Comment: Ah cool - that makes sense. Basically I am building a SDK which communicates with a resource server. Each user of the SDK will be given credentials. When the user creates a client, the credentials will be prompted for and if ok, an access token will be issued. What I got confused with is that the RFC states an expiry has to be specified. So if the token did expire, I was thinking of supplying a mechanism to refresh it. But I guess they will have to re-authenticate. That's my confusion.

Comment: the flow you have selected is more suited for a backoffice connection... maybe consider a `Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant` type flow if you can trust the client/server. (that one does have a refresh token and utelizes a username & password combo instead)

Comment: I just took a look and `Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant` fits my case perfectly. Thanks!